# How to access SCORM files from cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I am trying to access hosted scorm file from cloud storage where I made all files as public. While trying to access using the url:
https://host-name/training-thumbnails/000001/Objects_Simple_Secure_Scale-out_For_Unstructured_Data_439/course-b021871fbcfc62eb98f72f970bca482b.html

I am getting below error.[image: Error screenshot]

Does anybody has any idea why I am getting this error.

Note: I am using native scormApi to render the scorm files.

Comment: Are you accessing this course file via an LMS? Particularly an LMS with a SCORM player?

Comment: @BrianJ.Miller yes. I am accessing using LMS. LMS is running in my local and the scorm file is hosted on cloud. May be it is a cross domain issue?

Comment: (sorry for slow response) Yes, could well be a cross origin issue. The course files have to be on the same origin as the SCORM API provided by the LMS because it is looking through the JS global objects for the runtime interface.